# Deserializing JSON Date field in Python/Django

Tags: python, json, django, date

I am trying to port a web crawler app from .Net to Python. It receives json responses similar to the following:

```
[
  {
    "Code": "AAA",
    "Date": "/Date(1481875200000)/",
    "Value": 12345.00
  }
]
```

This could easily be deserialized by Newtonsoft Json. However I can't seem to deserialize this with Python's built in Json Decoder

```
from django.db import models

class ItemModel(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

import json

parsed_data = json.loads(json_data, encoding='utf-8')
new_model=ItemModel()
new_model.code = parsed_data["Code"]
new_model.date = parsed_data["Date"]
new_model.value = parsed_data["Value"]
new_model.save()
```

which gives

> ValidationError: [u"'/Date(1481875200000)/' value has an invalid
>   format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

Edit: Now I know this is caused because of assigning a string to a Date Time field

Is there a way to try parse this data to the django model? - as I have no way to modify the json response. Also is this the right way to do this? as the code seems intuitively iffy to me.

Comment: When I try that, it simply parses `"/Date(1481875200000)/"` as a string and never tries to do any date parsing (as one would expect, JSON doesn't have a date datatype). So you are doing something extra that you're not showing here.

Comment: Hmm makes sense, I was actually trying to set this field to a Django model DateTime field, so this is probably caused by setting a string to it. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a custom decoder for 'Date' field.

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

def parseMyData(dct):
    if 'Date' in dct:
        timestamp = int(dct['Date'][6:-2])
        dct['Date'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    return dct


jdata = '''{
"Code": "AAA",
"Date": "/Date(14818752000)/",
"Value": 12345.00
}
'''

json.loads(jdata,  object_hook=parseMyData)
```

and returns

```
{u'Code': u'AAA',
 'Date': datetime.datetime(2439, 8, 3, 10, 0),
 u'Value': 12345.0}
```

Comment: This code is needs to be slightly modified because the timestamp in my json is in miliseconds, so it should be int(dct['Date'][6:-2]) / 1000 instead. I don't know if I should be concerned about int being limited - shouldn't this be stored in a long (Int64) format instead? Anyway this still works. Thanks!

Comment: It is not limited. In python, a 'plain integer'  is automatically converted into a  'long integer' if it is too  big